# NASM 32-bit: printing content of register by printf

Tags: c, linux, assembly, printf, nasm

I'm new to assembly. I'm having different output for following simple code from what I expected. each time before `printf` is called, content of `eax` is shifted to the right by some number. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Code:

```
;file name : testing.asm
;assemble and link with:
;nasm -f elf testing.asm && gcc -m32 -o testing testing.o
extern  printf      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data       ; Data section, initialized variables

    a:  dd  15  ; int a=15
    str:    db "content in eax=%d", 10, 0 

SECTION .text       ; Code section.

    global main     ; the standard gcc entry point
main:               ; the program label for the entry point
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     eax, [a]    ; put a from store into register

    shr     eax, 1      ; eax content should be 15>>1 = 7
    push    eax     
    push    dword str   ; string to be printed
    call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)

    shr     eax, 2
    push    eax         ; eax content should be 7>>2 = 1
    push    dword str   
    call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)    

    shr     eax, 1  
    push    eax         ; eax content should be 1>>1 = 0
    push    dword str   
    call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)

    mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
    mov     eax, 0      ; normal, no error, return value
    ret                 ; return
```

Output:

```
content in eax=7
content in eax=4
content in eax=8
```

Expected Output:

```
content in eax=7
content in eax=1
content in eax=0
```

Comment: Your first four words:  "... *I'm new to assembly* ..."  For someone who is new to assembly, you certainly do write nice source code; neat, easily read at first glance, fully legible, and understandable to a stranger who has never seen you or your work before.  Continue this and you have a bright future.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` returns its result in `eax`, the original value is lost.

You should reload it from `[a]` or use a register that is saved across function calls such as `esi`, but you should save it as well and restore it before returning to the caller.  You should pop the arguments passed to `printf` with a `add esp,8` after each call to keep your stack frame consistent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Removed the typo.

Comment: It seems that `printf` changes content of `ecx` and `edx` also. Right?

Comment: @user148865: Yes it does on most systems.  You want to study the ABI to understand the specific details of your environment: register sue, parameter passing, system call conventions... You will find that easily with a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

In your data section you could just use an equate for `a` since you only use that variable once and do not change it (i'll call it `value`).

```
    fmt db "content in eax=%d",0xa,0
    value equ 15
```

In the main function i'm pretty sure (correct me if i'm wrong) that you're supposed to save the base pointer before you update it with the stack pointer.

```
main:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
```

Now you could create a local variable to store the current value you are working on.

```
sub esp, 4
```

From there you would just keep fetching, shifting and storing the value on the stack before each call to `printf`.

```
mov eax, value          ; move 15 into eax  
shr eax, 1              ; make first shift
mov dword[ebp-4], eax   ; store result in local variable

push eax                ; eax = 7
push fmt
call printf             
add esp, 8              ; clean eax & fmt off the stack

mov eax, [ebp-4]        ; fetch last shift result from variable
shr eax, 2              ; make second shift
mov dword[ebp-4], eax   ; store result back in variable

push eax                ; eax = 1
push fmt
call printf             
add esp, 8              

mov eax, [ebp-4]        ; fetch last shift result from variable
shr eax, 1              ; make last shift

push eax                ; eax = 0
push fmt
call printf             
add esp, 8

add esp, 4              ; clean local variable
```

And then remember, before you return, when you release the stack frame that you also restore (pop) the base pointer.

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

This should output:

```
content in eax=7
content in eax=1
content in eax=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) will return the number of characters transmitted to the output. So when you do this:

```
call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)

shr     eax, 2
```

You are actually shifting the result from printf:

- "content in eax=7\n" is 17 characters, so shitfting by 2 gives: 17 / 4 = 4

You need to save the value (either in a preserved register, on the stack or in memory) before shifting.

Comment: Silly question: str is "content in eax=7",10,0 . But, printf is returning 16.
Why newline and null characters aren't counted here?

Comment: They are counted! I corrected that already ;) However even `17 >> 4` is still `4` since the rest of the division by `2` get's thrown away.

Comment: @user148865 : yes, sorry, the `\n` should be counted for the total number  of characters in the output (so it's 17, not 16) but the return from `printf` excludes the null byte.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer seems not to be a good solution, I'm currently keeping it because of the discussion below**

---

Like others said, `printf` will return it's result to eax. The result of printf is the number of bytes written.

Since you pushed the result of the `shr` operation to the stack, you can retrieve them again using `pop`, like this:

```
shr     eax, 1      ; eax content should be 15>>1 = 7
push    eax    
push    dword str   ; string to be printed
call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)

pop     eax 
pop     eax 
shr     eax, 2
push    eax         ; eax content should be 7>>2 = 1
push    dword str   
call    printf      ; printf(str,content_of_eax)  

# and so on ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Instead of using `pop eax` twice, we can use `add esp,4` in place of first `pop eax`, right? which one should be preferred?

Comment: No this would work. It would increase the stack pointer over the borders of the stack, on the other hand it would not copy the right value into `eax`.. Using `pop` twice is pretty ok

Comment: Yes, I agree that it will work. My question is what is the best way to restore content to `eax`? Using `pop eax` twice, or using `add esp,4` in place of `pop eax`?

Comment: Sorry this was a typo, I meant it will *not* work. Have your tried it?

Comment: Yes, `add esp,4` and then `pop eax` instead of `pop eax` twice works.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Note that I'm also not the assembler professional. I just had a look here for fun. Yes, you can `add esp, 4` and then `pop eax`.. It is basically the same. However I think `pop eax` twice is better readable.

Comment: I agree. Especially if you want to throw away more than one value from stack before you pop the value of interest, something like add esp, 16 pop eax is faster (and looks better) then calling pop 5 times.

Comment: No, bad idea: popping the arguments does not guarantee you will restore the values pushed.  The function called may have modified them.  `printf` probably won't, but do not rely on it.

Comment: @chqrlie How do I guarantee that the values can be restored properly?

Comment: You push `eax`, then push the arguments (effectively pushing `eax` twice), call `printf`, restore the stack with `add esp,8`, then pop `eax` to restore its value.  You can save and restore the other registers the same way.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the difference between `pop eax` twice and `add esp,8` and then `pop eax`.  Isn't it basically the same? `pop` will implicitly `add 4` to `esp`. how should it work otherwise?

Comment: @chqrlie Sure, the `add N,esp` solution is faster as `N` grows and therefore preferable but they are doing the same logic, at least this what the manual says: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html (Search for *pop instructions* there)

Comment: These are two unrelated issues: you can adjust the stack with `add esp,8` or by popping a register multiple times: `pop eax; pop eax`.  The result is somewhat different: `pop` generates 1 byte of code, whereas `add esp,8` generates more code but is a single instruction without a side effect on `eax`.  If you need to adjust the stack for more than 1 argument, `add esp,xxx` is better.

Comment: Saving and restoring registers is a separate issue: you save them by pushing them on the stack before pushing the function arguments, then call the function, then adjust the stack, then finally pop the registers saved in reverse order.

Comment: Let me play around a bit with this to see the difference. As I said I've unfortunately not much practice with assembler anymore (We did some cool but educational stuff at university). Many thanks for your comments! Will try to reproduce them

Comment: @hek2mgl This might interest you, a fast way to save all the general purpose registers is to use `pushad` to push them on the stack and `popad` to pop them back off.